# Getting error when trying to find a value within an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, typescript

I have an array `rowSelected` which has `two` elements. Both the `elements` have `TaskType` value as below:

The first element has `TaskType: First`

The second element has `TaskType: Second`

Now, if any of the elements has `TaskType: First` then I want to make the boolean variable `this.myflag` as `true`

I am using `Array.find` as below:

```
const rowSelected = this.selection.selected;
            if (rowSelected.find(x => x.TaskType.includes('ABC'))) {
                this.myflag = true;
            }
```

The above code is giving an error `Property 'TaskType' does not exist on type 'TInterface'.`

However, when I do `rowSelected.find(x => console.log(x.TaskType))` I am able to print the `type` value

The `console.log(rowSelected)` is returning

```
0: {hostName: "ABC.COM",TaskType: "First", …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

The `TInterface` looks as below:

```
export interface TInterface {
    objectId: string;
    hostName: string;
}
```

I am not sure why it is complaining about `TInterface` as it is not at all related to `rowSelected`

Comment: It might not be captured in your types. Can you show type of `rowSelected` and `TInterface`?

Comment: The `typeof` is returning `object` for `rowSelected` How to address it?

Comment: Post a subset of your data set and `TInterface`

Comment: You could try replacing `x.type.includes('ABC')` with `x.TaskType.includes('ABC')`, or if that doesn't work post up what the TaskType interface looks like.

Comment: Looks like you tried the above and it didn't work. As @PritamKadam and @mwilson posted above, find `TInterface` in your code and post what is inside of it

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the culprit but is there a reason you are using `rowSelected.find`? I wonder if replacing your if statement with something like `rowSelected.forEach( x => { if ( x.TaskType.includes('ABC') ) { myflag = true } })` would work.

Comment: still getting the same error `Property 'TaskType' does not exist on type...`

Comment: What is the output for `rowSelected.forEach( x => { console.log(x) })`?

Comment: the output is `{hostName: "abc.com", TaskType: "First", …}`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be using `instanceof` instead of `.type` or `typeof`.

```
myflag = false
class First {
    name: string
}
const first: First = new First(name: "first")
class Second {
    name: string
}
const second: Second = new Second(name: "second")
let rowSelected = [
    first,
  second
]
rowSelected.forEach(x => { 
    if( x instanceof First ) {
        myflag = true;
    }
})
console.log(myflag)
```

Comment: This doesn't look correct. Here `type` is not the class type. It is a property of the object x

Comment: In that case I think there is something going on with the type of each element in rowSelected, because the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/q0det926/1/) works just fine. Can you post the result of `rowSelected.forEach(x => console.log(x))`?

Comment: I have updated my question. The `console.log(rowSelected)` is returning

    0: {hostName: "ABC.COM",TaskType: "ABC", …}
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array(0)